# Retrieving data from a table

Tags: php, html, css

I am relatively new in php,i am facing a problem while i retrieving data from a table of my database...the name of the table is 'leave'.more importantly i have to say that i can easily retrieve data from another table of the same database.I am using a open source database and 'leave' table is created by me.is that the reason??Actually i don't find any reason for this problem.i am using mysql_fetch_row(),but i have an error as follow

> Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\attendance_system\admin_leave.php on line 42
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'leave' at line 1

here is my code...please help me

code here

```
<?php
/*@session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username']) {

} else {

header("Location: index.php");
}
$title = 'Leave Application';*/
include_once 'config.php';
include('header.php');
?>
<div class="grid_12">
<div class="contentpanel">

    <h2 align="center">Leave Application</h2>

    <?php

        $sql =  mysql_query('select * from leave');

    ?>
    <table class="list" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <th>Employee ID</th>
                <th>Employee Name</th>
                <th>User Name</th>
                <th>Leave Days</th>
                <th>Start Date</th>
                <th>End Date</th>
                <th>Reason</th>


            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>

        <?php
           while($w= mysql_fetch_row($sql) or die(mysql_error()))
           {
              echo 
              "<tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>".$w[0]."</td>
              <td>".$w[1]."</td>
              <td>".$w[2]."</td>
              <td>".$w[3]."</td>
              <td>".$w[4]."</td>
              <td>".$w[5]."</td>
              <td>".$w[6]."</td>





              </tr>";

           }
        ?>


        </tbody>


    </table>
    <br/>
    <br/>
</div>
</div>
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Leave](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/leave.html) is a keyword in MySql

You need to put the table name in backticks.

Use this:

```
 $sql =  mysql_query('select * from `leave`');
```

Comment: mysql uses backticks, not brackets, to quote reserved words.